# Why no alias record could be found when I'm trying to sql-sync the database?

Tags: drush

I'm trying to synchronize a production database to two development installations at once, instead of having the production database dumped twice.

In `aliases.drush.inc` file I'm defining a site-list alias as following:

```
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'site-list' => array('@dev1', '@dev2'),
);

$aliases['prod'] = array(
  'uri' => 'default/prod',
  'root' => '/docroot/prod',
  'db-url' => 'mysqli://root:pass@localhost/prod',
);  
$aliases['dev1'] = array(
  'uri' => 'default/dev1',
  'root' => '/docroot/dev1',
  'db-url' => 'mysqli://root:pass@localhost/dev1',
);
$aliases['dev2'] = array(
  'uri' => 'default/dev2',
  'root' => '/docroot/dev2',
  'db-url' => 'mysqli://root:pass@localhost/dev2',
);
```

Running a Drush command against any of these aliases works fine.

Running `drush @dev status` works fine too, and displays the status for both `@dev1` and `@dev2`.

However, trying to execute `drush sql-sync @prod @dev` gives me the following error:

> Error: no alias record could be found for @dev

Do you have any clues?

Comment: What happens when you run `drush sql-sync @prod @dev1`? What happens when you run `drush sql-sync @prod @dev.dev1`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is buggy in Drush and will be removed. Check this out: http://drupal.org/node/1316378

Comment: @Remon You should place that as the answer and close this out then. Looks like you have the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that this feature is buggy in Drush and will be removed. Check this out: [drupal.org/node/1316378](http://drupal.org/node/1316378)

Answer (score 1):

Drush 8+ expects a site alias file. For me it turned out that the drush/sites/self.site.yml didn't exist after I've run into a similar error. The alias file didn't got copied properly into a container.

You need to ensure that the alias file exists.

> ```bash
> $ drush sql-sync @test @self -y
> Error: no alias record could be found for source [error]
> @test
> ```

Here's a nice article about Drush Site Aliases for Drupal 8 and Drupal 9 and how this actually is supposed to work in detail: https://drupalize.me/tutorial/drush-site-aliases?p=2458

Answer (score 0):

copy the DB array from your settings to your aliases file.